# Stop a div 100px from top of document after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having random results with window scrolling. I basically click on a box, open it and it expands. Once expanded, the window should scroll to it, stopping it 100px from the top of the browser window, but it doesn't and it's a bit random, not all boxes stops at the same distance form the window.

This is what i mean i'm working on, expand the box and see: 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(".opened").position().top - 100}, 2000);
```

Use `position()` over `offset()`.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Thanks but i get random results actually, not all boxes stop 100px from top

Comment: I had a look at your other post - and your test link. It seems your code says -240 rather than -100.
Also, you can't scroll to 'empty space'. Once you've reached the top of the document, it won't scroll up any further. So the first row or two of items won't be centered, they'll be nearer the top. As an edit, instead of using `scrollTop` on the `html`/`body` - you could adjust the `marginTop` on the containing element.

Comment: ye sorry, i thought at first one simple question would solve so just used examples 100px. If i use marginTop i won't have the window scrolling tho

Comment: or are you saying to animate marginTop on the container on each click when we expand the box? if so i will have to know each row height, maybe complicating my life

Comment: use `position()` instead of `offset()` - as this will give you the distance between the container and the top of your expanded box. Then use a negative `marginTop` on your container, except this time ADD 100 pixels. http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: actually that just worked fine: $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(".opened").position().top}, 2000); no need of -240px with position(), thanks! p.s. I don't event need negative margins actually as the top header is fixed so always available. Feel free to post it as answer and i'll accept it.  Thanks again